# Power over Ethernet for Cisco EPC3928

Tags: networking

Does anybody know if the Cisco epc 3928 supports a power over ethernet connection to my access points installed around the house ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **no**

The Cisco device itself does not have PoE ports. Of course you could use a PoE capable switch or a PoE injector to power your access points and connect them to the Cisco router.